# Backup restoring differently than how it used to

Tags: users, database, backups

I posted a question yesterday, which ended with someone telling me to figure out how my backups are managed and then to ask another question with more details, so here I am.

About a week ago my boss backed up and installed a dev server for his site, so that I could play around with it and learn Drupal without messing up the live version.

About 2 days ago I updated all of my modules and Drupal core to 7.42 from 7.41. The next day I noticed that the login page, where the user has to log in before being able to access the rest of the site, no longer exists. Now when I go to my dev site it shows the main page with the login form somewhere near the bottom, along with all of the menus and everything that you should only be able to see while logged in. You can't actually access the menu links, as when you do it loops back to this same page since it requires a login, but users aren't even supposed to be able to see the links before they login.

I tried restoring the original backup (the one used to create this dev version from scratch) onto the dev site, but the same issue happened. I thought it may be something with the SQL, so I restored the databases using that same original backup; same thing happened. I tried installing the backup onto different versions of drupal too: 6.42, 7.41 (the version that it was originally on), 7.42(the one it updated to that I thought broke it), and the 7.x dev one. Same thing happened on every one.

I tried doing a complete reset, uninstalling and reinstalling lamp, but nothing changed then either.

After doing some searching through the files, I found that the only reference to the image used on the live site's correct page is in the blogger theme's style.css file, which confused me because the rest of the site uses the lexus zymphonies theme. I'm not sure if this means anything, but it's the only real lead I have here about anything related to that page.

Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tried installing the backup on different versions of Drupal? Please elaborate what kind of backup files you have and how you tried to restore them.